# Developing NEST Universal App for Windows 10

Tags: nest-api

Are there any hidden restrictions/costs for developing a NEST application for the Windows platform? I've noticed an iOS and Andriod SDK is available, but presumably the Javascript alternative should suffice?

Does the NEST camera support an open standard for integrating streaming video into a Windows application?

Comment: Did you look at the Nest REST API option?

Answer (score 1):

The API is web based and does not put any limitations on being built on Windows, there just isn't a Windows based SDK.

The Nest Cams currently do not support streaming of any type via the API.